# Setting multiple referenceColumns using one JoinFormula

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Our database model uses a single History table to record all inserts and updates to our applications tables.  There is no primary key on the table, but a composite key can be made up of the entityId, tableName, columnName, and eventDate.  I'd like to be able to create a OneToOne relationship on each entity that uses the History table to return the lastUpdatedEvent.  I can get the record I want using a JoinFormula, but Hibernate then wants to join back to the History table using the id retrieved from the JoinFormula which isn't unique by itself.

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
  name = "graph.User.All",
  attributeNodes = {
    @NamedAttributeNode("lastUpdatedEvent"),
  }
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private String user_id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT * FROM (SELECT h.id FROM history h WHERE h.id =     user_id and h.tableName = 'USER' ORDER BY h.event_date DESC) WHERE rownum = 1)", referenceColumn = "entityId"))
  private History lastUpdatedEvent;

...
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HISTORY")
public clas History {

  @EmbeddedId
  private HistoryId id;

  @Embeddable
  public static class HistoryId {

    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String entityId;

    @Column(name = "TABLENAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String tableName;

    @Column(name = "EVENT_DATE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime eventDate;
    
    @Column(name = "COLUMNNAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String columnName;

...
```

I've tried creating an EmbeddedId in the History entity with the 4 fields mentioned above, but then Hibernate complains that it's expecting 4 but only received 1.  I'm guessing I could use the same join formula for the 3 other reference columns, but that's obviously not efficient. I could also set the lastUpdateEvent after I retrieve the entity, but I'd like to be able to sort them by the lastUpdatedDate.  So is there a way to set multiple referenceColumns using one JoinFormula or is there another approach that would work better?